# SQL how to find tables with more than 1 row with criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database of over 6000 tables.  I am looking for tables that have certain criteria populated (ie `person_id = 123`).

Is this possible?

I can get a list of tables with `row count > 0` that have person_id but want to find tables with `person_id = 123` and `rowcount > 0`.

This gives a list of tables with `person_id` and `rowcount`.

```
select distinct t.name as tablename, p.rows as cnt 
from sys.columns c 
inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
WHERE 
    t.is_ms_shipped = 0
AND
 t.name in (select t1.name  from sys.columns c1 inner join sys.tables t1 on c1.object_id = t1.object_id
where c1.name = 'person_id') 
order by 2
```

Comment: I think you will need dynamic SQL here, to build the exact query you want to run using a dynamic table name.

Comment: I guess you need a cursor on the result-set of your query that creates SELECTS from the returned tables into a dynamic-sql string and run them all. Alternatively, concatenate them all with XML using a union in between

Comment: Over 6000 tables?!? Looks like a nightmare db design.

Comment: Are there foreign keys that enforce the relationship on that field?

Comment: Just going to leave this here. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal

Comment: @Rob, please mind that row count cannot always give you exact result [Reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8ed9cbad-2745-457e-ab95-3fc5fdd423f2/row-count-problem-with-sysdmdbpartitionstats?forum=transactsql)

Comment: Tim's comment is the answer.   now this question will never get closed.  : (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    TableName       NVARCHAR(255)
    , [RowCount]    INT
)

DECLARE Csr cursor for
SELECT DISTINCT t.[name] AS tablename
FROM sys.columns c 
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t 
        ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.[name] = 'PersonID'

DECLARE
    @TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(255)
    , @SQL  VARCHAR(MAX)

set nocount on
OPEN Csr
FETCH NEXT FROM Csr INTO @TABLE_NAME
WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
 BEGIN
    IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
     BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #tmp (TableName, [RowCount]) SELECT ''' + @TABLE_NAME + ''', COUNT(*) FROM ' + @TABLE_NAME + ' WHERE PersonID = 123'
    EXECUTE(@SQL)
     END
    FETCH NEXT FROM Csr INTO @TABLE_NAME    
 END
CLOSE Csr
DEALLOCATE Csr

SELECT *
FROM #tmp
WHERE [RowCount] > 0

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do it for you using a cursor:

```
declare @t varchar(100)
    ,@sql varchar(max)

create table #finished (tbls varchar(100))

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
select table_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
where column_name = 'person_id'

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @t 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
      set @sql ='insert into #finished
             select distinct ''' +@t + ''''+
             ' from ' + @t +
             ' where person_ID=123'

      exec(@sql)

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @t 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor


select * from #finished
drop table #finsihed
```

Comment: this will not work, the select inside the exec is referring to the table variable **@finished** which is defined in the beginning of your script. This is a different scope and can't be done this way. The subselect is also really odd. distinct **@t** from **@t**

Comment: I changed it a little. I actually wrote the code in editor.

Comment: the distinct @t from @t will return the table name once if the where results in more that one occurance.

Answer (score 0):

With dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE 
    @stm nvarchar(max),
    @err int
SET @stm = N''

SELECT @stm = @stm + CONCAT(
         'UNION ALL ',
        'SELECT ''', 
        sysobjects.name, 
        ''' AS TableName, COUNT(*) AS RecordCount ',
        'FROM [',
        sysobjects.name,
        '] WHERE ',
        syscolumns.name,
        ' = 123 HAVING COUNT(*) > 0 ')
    FROM sysobjects 
    INNER JOIN syscolumns on sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
    WHERE (sysobjects.xtype = 'U') AND (syscolumns.name = 'person_ID')

SET @stm = STUFF(@stm, 1, 10, '')
PRINT @stm

EXEC @err = sp_executesql @stm
IF @err = 0 
    PRINT 'OK'
ELSE 
    PRINT 'Error'
```